# How to reset Arduino from software

Tags: serial, reset

As you know, the Arduino IDE resets the Arduino when the Serial Monitor is opened. I want also my program to do it. But I don't know how.

I examined the source code of the Arduino IDE (Serial.java & SerialMonitor.java), but I can't find where it sends the reset command. Where is it?

I use C# to communicate with serial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I have solved this by sending DSR pulse as seen on code below:

```
mySerial.DtrEnable = true;
mySerial.Open();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
mySerial.DtrEnable = false;
```

Comment: FYI: The Leonardo's reset is triggered when the Leonardo's virtual (CDC) serial / COM port is opened at 1200 baud and then closed